# RavenDB: Updating all null values of properties of all documents to a value

Tags: ravendb

I have Documents like this in RavenDB 2.5:

```
public class SomeDocument {
    public int Id { get;set; }

    ...other properties...

    public bool ShowMember { get;set; }
}
```

with the `ShowMember` property being newly added.

Now I want to set `ShowMember` to `true` on all documents where it isn't set already.

I tried doing this with Eval Patching like this:

```
store.DatabaseCommands.UpdateByIndex("Raven/DocumentsByEntityName",
                new IndexQuery { Query = "Tag:SomeDocuments" },
                new ScriptedPatchRequest() { 
                      Script = @"if(this.ShowMember == null){ 
                                     this.ShowMember = true;
                                 }" });
```

the operation completes without any errors, but documents that already have `ShowMember` set are still updated, despite the `if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with it some more, doing

```
if(this.ShowMember == undefined)
```

seems to work.

Both

```
if(this.ShowMember == null)
```

and

```
if(!this.ShowMember)
```

don't work.